# WEKA: How to filter multiple attribute ranges?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, classification

This is what I usually do to select an attribute range in weka

```
String[] options = new String[2];
options[0] = "-R";                                    // "range"
options[1] = "1-2"; 

Remove remove = new Remove();                         // new instance of filter
remove.setOptions(options);
```

Now, I need to remove attribute field 4 as well, how can I specify this in options[1] ?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Remove API](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Remove.html) describes the attributes to be removed as a comma-separated list, 
so I think you should use:

```
options[1] = "1-2,4";
```